# How to give paragraphs in an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, parser-combinators, paragraphs

I am building an app for an University. As required I am adding paragraphs taking separate TextView for each paragraphs. Is there a way where i can give paragraphs combined. Its just my thought on whether this is possible? Here is the code snippet i worked on.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
android:inputType="numberSigned"
android:text="+91 12 12345678" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:inputType="phone"
android:text="+91 12 12345678" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
android:autoLink="email"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:text="admissions@abc.edu" />
```

Here in my code I want to give the two phone numbers and the email id combined in a single TextView. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use `WebView` or `TextView` with `Html` formatted text? It support paragraph and more tags. Then it doesn't required separate Textview for each paragraph.

Comment: @user370305, "WebView", OK I will use. But how to do with Html formatted text? Guide me, I am a newbie to android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your prorbelm.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String htmlText = "<p> +91 12 12345678 </p> <p> +91 12 12345678 </p> <p> admissions@abc.edu </p>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It works fine. But alignment is missing out. How can I do that? And what if I have lengthy paragraphs? Can I do the same? Will not the .java file become more clumsy?

Comment: if you learn more about html code you can easily handle your more problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to do this in XML, only possible using multiple text views... You can possibly do it programmatically, with html converting.

Also you should remove the **android:inputType=""** from each, they are for EditText, not TextView.

Comment: Thank You. I accept your answer for this--android:inputType=""

Answer (score 0):

1. highlight the text you want to become a paragraph in your xml file and press **alt+enter**
2. Select the option "**Extract as string"** and press **enter**.
3. The text will then automatically become a string written inside the
   last line of your strings.xml file which is inside the res/values
   folder of any Android studio native project..
4. Now edit the text by adding **\n** in between where you want to
   break the sentence text into a paragraph..

   Done, and simple,  you're welcome

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it is better to use one TextView and give it an **android:src="@string/your_string"** attribute.

Then go into **res->values->strings** and add:

```
<string name="your_string">Everything you want to display write it here</string>
```

Hope i helped.

Comment: This does not help with the paragraphs, so it's really more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Kindly, improve answer to directly answer the question which concerns Paragraphs..   What you have said is only a comment about making strings.. it doesn't solve the paragraph question..   thank you